# Can sshfs mount the local disks?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sshfs, fuse

hello I have been installed libfuse and sshfs in my ubuntu and the kernel version is 4.4.0-38.

And now I want to `sshfs user@localhost:/dir /mnt`. but it always shows the error message:

> read: Connection reset by peer

How come it always happened? Is there anyway to mount a disk by fuse?

Comment: You're missing the port.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I tried, still not.
eg. sshfs -o port=1234 user@localhost:/home /mnt

Comment: What does the pure `ssh` reports? `ssh -vvv user@localhost`? Did you set up the access?

Comment: @Jakuje sorry, how to set up the access? thanks

Comment: @Jakuje Oh, I knew. I didn't install the openssh-server on ubuntu, it closed default. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the pure ssh in debug mode (`ssh -vvv user@localhost`) will give you a guide what is wrong. In this case, you need to install the `openssh-server` package to have where to connect.

Comment: BTW, Is there anyway to mount 2 filesystems by FUSE? thx

Comment: Yes, but you need to choose different mount point.

Comment: any words about that?